# Find String from String using NSRegularExpression Swift

Tags: swift, nsregularexpression, swift2

I want to fetch url of images from the `String` using NSRegularExpression.

```
func findURlUsingExpression(urlString: String){

    do{

        let expression = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\b(http|https)\\S*(jpg|png)\\b", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)

        let arrMatches = expression.matchesInString(urlString, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, urlString.characters.count))

        for match in arrMatches{

            let matchText = urlString.substringWithRange(Range(urlString.startIndex.advancedBy(match.range.location) ..< urlString.startIndex.advancedBy(match.range.location + match.range.length)))
            print(matchText)
        }

    }catch let error as NSError{

        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

It works with just the simple string but not with the `HTML` `String`.

**Working Example:**

```
let tempString = "jhgsfjhgsfhjgajshfgjahksfgjhs http://jhsgdfjhjhggajhdgsf.jpg jahsfgh asdf ajsdghf http://jhsgdfjhjhggajhdgsf.png"

findURlUsingExpression(tempString)
```

**Output:**

```
http://jhsgdfjhjhggajhdgsf.jpg
http://jhsgdfjhjhggajhdgsf.png
```

But not working with this one: http://www.writeurl.com/text/478sqami3ukuug0r0bdb/i3r86zlza211xpwkdf2m

Answer (score 2):

Don't roll your own regex if you can help it. Easiest and safest way is to use `NSDataDetector`. By using `NSDataDetector` you leverage a pre-built, heavily used parsing tool which should already have most of the bugs shaken out of it.

Here is a good article on it: [NSData​Detector](http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/)

> NSDataDetector is a subclass of NSRegularExpression, but instead of
>   matching on an ICU pattern, it detects semi-structured information:
>   dates, addresses, links, phone numbers and transit information.

```
import Foundation

let tempString = "jhgsfjhgsfhjgajshfgjahksfgjhs http://example.com/jhsgdfjhjhggajhdgsf.jpg jahsfgh asdf ajsdghf http://example.com/jhsgdfjhjhggajhdgsf.png"

let types: NSTextCheckingType = [.Link]
let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)
detector?.enumerateMatchesInString(tempString, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, (tempString as NSString).length)) { (result, flags, _) in
  if let result = result?.URL {
    print(result)
  }
}

// => "http://example.com/jhsgdfjhjhggajhdgsf.jpg"
// => "http://example.com/jhsgdfjhjhggajhdgsf.png"
```

The example is from that site, adapted to search for a link.

Comment: I will try and let you know!

Comment: It works but returns wrong link - `http://i-wallpapers.blogspot.com/2011/12/christmas-iphone-wallpapers.html&quot;,imgurl:&quot;http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-w6JW7Dif8kc/TvDIZcOX7nI/AAAAAAAAAQg/9-7TXCZlutM/s1600/iphone_christmas_wallpaper+%25282%2529.jpg`

Comment: Is that the string you're trying to parse or is that a site you're visiting to get data to parse?

Comment: Just now, I tried to get URL from here! `http://www.bing.com/images/async?q=Wallpapers%20Christmas%20Wallpapers&async=content&first=1&count=35&dgsrr=true&qft=+filterui:imagesize-large+filterui:aspect-tall`

Comment: When I visit that link I don't get any parsable HTML content, just some structure.

Comment: View the Source, that's the `data` I am calling from `NSURL`

Comment: OK, so you're trying to get links like: `http://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?q=Vintage+Wallpaper+Patterns&amp;w=100&amp;h=100&amp;c=1&amp;rs=1&amp;qlt=90&amp;pid=InlineBlock&amp;mkt=en-US&amp;adlt=moderate&amp;t=1&amp;mw=247` ?

Comment: Yes! That's the reason, I am going for `NSRegularExpression`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108279/discussion-between-kenneth-bruno-and-sohil-r-memon).